# Is current directory of postgres.exe always the data folder?

Tags: postgresql

I'm making a FDW (Foreign Data Wrapper) in PostgreSQL for myself using C, and I'd like to know if the current directory of the process (`postgres.exe` in my case) is always the data folder,
and would not be changed for its life time. It seems so in my experience, but is that always true?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the postmaster changes the current working directory to the data directory during startup, and that setting is inherited by all backend processes. See the code in `src/backend/utils/init/miscinit.c` that is called for this:

```c
/*
 * Change working directory to DataDir.  Most of the postmaster and backend
 * code assumes that we are in DataDir so it can use relative paths to access
 * stuff in and under the data directory.  For convenience during path
 * setup, however, we don't force the chdir to occur during SetDataDir.
 */
void
ChangeToDataDir(void)
{
    Assert(DataDir);

    if (chdir(DataDir) < 0)
        ereport(FATAL,
                (errcode_for_file_access(),
                 errmsg("could not change directory to \"%s\": %m",
                        DataDir)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and a happy new year!